# How to make an a check to undefined

Tags: javascript

I have got a project, where need to make a check to undifined. How can i do it, because, if i try:

```
  var sorted_arr = arrayOfParasites.sort((b, a) => a[1] - b[1]);
  console.log(sorted_arr)
```

It takes an exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Only you know where `arrayOfParasites` is defined and assigned a value.

Comment: You've got an exception because value of arrayOfParasites is undefined

Comment: `arrayOfParasites?.sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1])`

Answer (score 1):

the optional chaining operator in JS. By adding the `?` before the method, it will return `undefined` instead of throwing an error if that method doesn't exist for that variable/type

```js
var arrayOfParasites = undefined;
var sorted_arr = arrayOfParasites?.sort((b, a) => a[1] - b[1]);
  console.log(sorted_arr)
```